# Which RFC's should one refer to, if one wishes to build an email client?

Tags: email

There are many RFC's.

Which are the RFC's that one must refer to in order to build an email client that is compatible with most (if not all), free email services (such as gmail, yahoo mail, iCloud, outlook) etc, which are not dependent on a proprietary client ?

I am aware of some of the different protocols, such as POP3 and IMAP, and have even built some simple email clients in college. I am trying to compile an exhaustive list of RFC / specifications that one must implement for different protocols to create an email client which is compatible with most email services.

Answer (score 1):

as you have noted the basics already (POP/IMAP), I'll point you towards:

RFC 2076 - Deals with user agents
RFC 5068 - E-mail message submission
RFC 5322 - Deals specially with message headers and formatting of said headers.
RFC 6409 - Mail message submission

See http://www.imapwiki.org/ImapRFCList for any and all RFCs relating to IMAP.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Historically, the Internet Mail Consortium attempted to maintain a list of RFCs for various purposes.  The site is no longer maintained, but the [archived RFC page (archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20120604063939/http://www.imc.org/rfcs.html) should be a good starting point.  It will obviously be incomplete and out of date, but may still be useful as a starting point.

The biggest hurdle for newcomers seems to be the plethora of overlapping and extending standards for various purposes.  The basic stack is RFC5322 plus MIME; additional content types within the MIME framework is obviously a forever changing and growing topic.  The relatively recent IDNA additions and internationalization in general is also a very complicated business, with many different amendments to many different standards to accommodate the extensions.  (For example, an [IDNA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5890) host name uses a completely different encoding than the same string in a [MIME file name](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231), which is again different from the same string in a [display header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047).)